# Akka: how to check what behaviour the actor has at the moment

Tags: scala, akka

My actor has two behaviours:

```
context.become(running)
context.become(stopped)
```

How to determine in the same actor, what is the current behaviour? Here is the full code:
http://pastie.org/private/r1dfdss62kcz9e2fzorrq

**New version**
http://pastie.org/private/b2h65n2dthjhxlnuq5caw

I decided to move the code to links because stackoverflow doesn't let me post the code here.

Comment: Send it another message and see how it behaves when it receives that message.  If that matches the expected behavior of the new state then the switch indeed happened.

Comment: Yes, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: You only interface with actors by sending messages.  Otherwise, you break the point of the actor model.

Comment: In looking at your example, your two receives each has a message that they handle that the other ones does not.  So if you don't want to follow my initial suggestion of sending another message then you could call `underlyingActor.receive.isDefinedAt(msg)` with different types depending on the state you want to check.  Use `Stop` to see if in the `running` state and `KeepAlive` to check if in the `stopped` state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Akka FSM to implement the same behaviour instead of using become. With Akka FSM, you have to ability to register for state change notifications. Refer http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html#External_Monitoring.

```
sealed trait State
case object Running extends State
case object Stopped extends State

case object Data

case object KeepAlive
case object Stop
case object CheckIfRunning

class EventsFeedActor extends Actor with FSM[State, Data.type] {
  startWith(Stopped, Data)
  when(Stopped) {
    case Event(KeepAlive, Data) => {
      ???
      goto(Running)
    }
    case Event(CheckIfRunning, Data) => {
      ???
      stay
    }
  }

  when(Running) {
    case Event(Stop, Data) => {
      ???
      goto(Stopped)
    }
    case Event(CheckIfRunning, Data) => {
      ???
      stay
    }
  }
}
```

With this, interested actors can send a `SubscribeTransitionCallBack(self)` to the EventFeedActor and will receive `CurrentState(actorRef, stateName)` immediately and a `Transition(actorRef, oldState, newState)` on every further state transition.

Comment: Switching to FSM just for testability seems not the best approach.  Plus, with only two possible states, FSM seems a bit overkill IMO.

Comment: Well, there is no other way achieve your needs. Also, I always default to FSMs. If I cant fit something into FSM, only then go with a general Actor.

Comment: If it is just for testing purposes then I'd suggest using the EventFilter mechanism https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/testing.html#expecting-log-messages. Just log the switching of behaviours and then test against those log messages to prove the behaviour has been changed .